# Intercept e-mails sent by Twilio during testing [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, twilio

I use for mail tasks a rails gem recipient_interceptor, with that my application won't send an email to actual users while during testing.

Is there something similar for twilio? How can I tackle this problem with twilio?

Comment: You mean automated tests or manual tests? Can you show one example of code that uses such interception?

Comment: Standard practice would be, in the absence of a library that intercepts those e-mails, using patterns such as Adapter or Bridge to create a layer separating your Twilio service calls from your application's code. This way, during testing, be it automated or manual, you can fake those calls, sending them to STDOUT or wherever you want.

Comment: Twilio has a set of [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) for manual tests but does not seem to have a test mode that will disable API calls. But since its just a HTTP REST API client  you can use any of the normal HTTP mocking libraries such Webmock and VCR to mock out the HTTP calls.

Comment: You can also use [Faradays built in Test adapter](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/docs/adapters/testing.md). https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby#customizing-your-http-client